# Javascript mouse event change boolean two times in one call

Tags: javascript, events, boolean, mouse

Im trying to change boolean value from false to true and back in one event call.

I tried smth like this: http://pastebin.com/7JVg11Ya

Without setTimeout, my function is flickering until mouseup event is called.

EDIT: updated pastebin link with more info.

Comment: Need more information. engine.input in your code is some external library call, which obviously have some side effects.

Comment: engine is my made library.

Comment: So basicly you got multiply calls of one mousedown handler for one real click? Btw please add all your code to question according to so rules

Comment: If i understood what you sead, then yes.
Here is git repo https://github.com/Reenasyoo/Purplust